# Split string to list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list, split

How can i split the following SVG 'd' string to list of objects

```
input = "M 13.09765625 -4.82421875 L 107 -4.82421875" 

output = [
         ['M', 13.097, -4.824], // values are float and 3 decimal long
         ['L', 107, -4.824]
         ]
```

```
input = "M 68.609375 130.265625 
         L 175.87890625 130.265625
         C 175.87890625 130.265625 111.0706329345703 197.2464141845703 175.87890625 262.0546875
         L 68.609375 130.265625
         Z"

output = [['M', 68.609375, 130.265625],
         ['L', 175.87890625, 130.265625],
         ['C', 175.87890625, 130.265625, 111.0706329345703, 197.2464141845703, 175.87890625, 262.0546875],
         ['L', 68.609375, 130.265625],
         ['Z']"
```

My approach was something like this which needs more tweaks

```
    path = "M 13.09765625 -4.82421875 L 107 -4.82421875";
    path = path.replace(/M/g, "\nM");
    path = path.replace(/L/g, "\nL");
    path = path.trim().split("\n");

    let segments = [];

    path.forEach(function (p, i) {
        segments.push(p.trim().split(" "));
    });
```

Comment: Be aware that the segment prefixes can be absolute, relative, with white-spaces, without white-spaces or omitted entirely when repeated.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex approach that describes the full match and has capture groups to isolate the parts you want.

It uses `.exec()` in a loop, which will return `null` on the first failure.

```js
const input = "M 13.09765625 -4.82421875 L 107 -4.82421875";

const re = /([ML]) (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g
let match = null;
const result = [];

while ((match = re.exec(input))) {
  result.push(match.slice(1));
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is a regex here not a litle over kill and slow for huge amount of data ?

Comment: Perhaps. Still an option.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but could you update it a little so that it work on the second example I add in my question?

Comment: @towhid: you should not update your question to a new question. Also there are more prefixes.. *Z, M, L, C, Q, A, H, V, S, T, z, m, l, c, q, a, h, v, s, t* and also segments with no prefixes. If you want a path segment parser I suggest to take tested existing polyfills instead of writing one on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but does the job

```js
const input = "M 13.09765625 -4.82421875 L 107 -4.82421875";
const output = [];


const chunks = input.split(" ");


for(let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i += 3){  
  output.push([
    chunks[i + 0],
    chunks[i + 1],
    chunks[i + 2]
  ]);  
}


console.log(output)
```

Thanks to @slappy for the comment, you can write it a litle shorter:

```js
for(let i=0; i < chunks.length; i += 3){  
  output.push(chunks.slice(i, i+3));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on @towhid comment, here the updated soulution.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d for the "d" path in SVG graphics.

```js
const input = "M 68.609375 130.265625 L 175.87890625 130.265625 C 175.87890625 130.265625 111.0706329345703 197.2464141845703 175.87890625 262.0546875 C 240.6871795654297 326.8629455566406 175.87890625 385.16796875 175.87890625 385.16796875 L 68.609375 385.16796875 L 68.609375 130.265625 Z"

const output = [];

const regex = RegExp('[A-Z]')
const chunks = input.trim().split(" ");

let counter = 0;
let offset = -1;


while(chunks.length > counter){
  
  if(regex.test(chunks[counter])){  
    offset += 1;
    output[offset] = []; 
  }
   
  output[offset].push(chunks[counter]); 
  counter += 1;
  
}


console.log(output)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution. A little shorter with `output.push(chunks.slice(i, i+3))`

Comment: @slappy Thanks, editet my answer and gave credits to you ;)

Comment: the string can be something like this..when this solution won't work

`M 68.609375 130.265625 L 175.87890625 130.265625 C 175.87890625 130.265625 111.0706329345703 197.2464141845703 175.87890625 262.0546875 C 240.6871795654297 326.8629455566406 175.87890625 385.16796875 175.87890625 385.16796875 L 68.609375 385.16796875 L 68.609375 130.265625 Z`

Comment: Fails on `M0 0 l10 10 20 30 30 20Z`.

Comment: @JavaScript But its exactly the output @towhid want, see in his question the `output` array.

Comment: How is `["M0", "0", "l10", "10", "20", "30", "30"], ["20Z"]` the output he wants?

Comment: `M0 0 l10 10 20 30 30 20Z` is not his input data. I used his posted input.

Comment: In that case your output has to return a wrong array on the `M` element (see his output). Dont worry, he will update his question soon enough again once he discovers more variations of PathSegments.

Answer (score 1):

First `split` string by space. Go thru the elements and group them when ever we find the alphabet.

```js
const input =
  "M 68.609375 130.265625 L 175.87890625 130.265625 C 175.87890625 130.265625 111.0706329345703 197.2464141845703 175.87890625 262.0546875 C 240.6871795654297 326.8629455566406 175.87890625 385.16796875 175.87890625 385.16796875 L 68.609375 385.16796875 L 68.609375 130.265625 Z";

const split = (str) => {
  const arr = str.split(" ");
  const output = [];
  let last = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (["M", "C", "L", "Z"].includes(arr[i]) || !arr[i]) {
      output.push(arr.slice(last, i));
      last = i;
    }
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(split(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can write (but it's not short form):

```
const input = "M 13.09765625 -4.82421875 L 107 -4.82421875";
const output:any = [];

const regex = /[A-Z]/g;
const pathn = input.split(" ");
pathn.forEach(function (p, i) {
    if (p.split(regex)[0].length === 0) {
        let index = pathn.indexOf(p);
        let px = [pathn[index], pathn[index + 1], pathn[index + 2]];
           output.push(px);
    }
    });
 console.log(output);
```